# In Django, how to render static/base.html file on browser?

Tags: python, html, django

I've changed **settings.py** as follows.

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mytweets.urls'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'static',
    ),
]
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        BASE_DIR + '/templates/'
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
        'loaders': (
             'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
             'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ),
    },
},]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I have changed **views.py** file as follows.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
class Index(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('I am called from a get Request')
    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('I am called from a post Request')
```

Then I have changed url.py file as follows.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from tweets.views import Index
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Finally I have made **base.html** file.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 
 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <h1 class="text-info">Hello Django!</h1>
    {% endblock %}
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The tutorial says that When I execute **$python manage.py runserver**, I'll see **"Hello Django"** that depends on **base.html**.
But I can see **"I am called from a get Request"** that depends on **views.py**.
I wanna know what's wrong and How can I render **base.html**?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have been learning Django for a week, so I appreciate for telling me what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In views.py you need to render your template as in [Django Documetation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/) and should do as the following code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class Index(View):
    template_name = 'base.html'

    def get(self, request):
          return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've changed views.py file but exception occur. **Request Method:  GET,
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/,
Django Version:  1.8.7,
Exception Type:  ImproperlyConfigured,
Exception Value:  

app_dirs must not be set when loaders is defined.

Exception Location:  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/engine.py in __init__, line 36,
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python**

Comment: @YuiryKozlenko this is a completely different issue, probably you have change something in `TEMPLATES` var in setting.py, look this [issue](https://github.com/django-admin-tools/django-admin-tools/issues/43)

Answer (score 2):

Modify your views.py to the following:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
class Index(View):
    template_name = 'base.html'
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('I am called from a get Request')
    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('I am called from a post Request')
    def get(self, request):
          return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. I have changed the views.py as above, but exception has occurred. **Exception Type:  ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:  

app_dirs must not be set when loaders is defined.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base.html'
```